# Происхождение названий внутренних органов

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Обсуждение слов "мозг" и "можжевельник" натолкнуло на размышления о происхождении названий внутренних органов. Я знаю, что слово "мышца" происходит от слова "мышь", на которую похожа (правда, я сходства особого не вижу))), сердце — середина, позвоночник, легкие — понятно. А вот, например, "желудок" и особенно "печень". Неужели у слов "печь", "печенье" и "печень" общий корень?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Желудок - от общеславянского zelodb (желудь), желудок якобы по форме напоминает его. Хотя, если не ошибаюсь, проникло в русский как церковнославянизм.

Печень - да, родственно "печь", более того исходно является одной из форм древнерусского причастия к "печь". Видимо характерные последствия постоянных возлияний и обжорства были хорошо знакомы нашим предкам.

Comment: температура печени выше, чем других органов.

Comment: Вряд ли это могло лечь в основу названия. Оно горазде древнее всех этих медицинских фактов. Фасмер предполагает связь скорее с традиционным для Греции способом приготовления гусиной печени. А уже в русский могло попасть как калька. Но тоже натянуто.

Answer (score 0):

Просто реплика. В современном русском языке *стоматолог* - тот, кто занимается зубами и ротовой полостью пациента. Аналогичное значение было у слова в греческом языке:

> др.-греч. στόμα (στόματος) «рот, уста» (восходит к праиндоевр. *stom-en- «рот») (Вики)

Но слово stomach переводится (с английского) как "живот", "желудок"!